Как std::string преобразовать в System::string
std::map<int, std::string> DayWeek;
DayWeek[0] = "Суббота";
DayWeek[1] = "Воскресенье";
DayWeek[2] = "Понедельник";
DayWeek[3] = "Вторник";
DayWeek[4] = "Среда";
DayWeek[5] = "Четверг";
DayWeek[6] = "Пятница"; 

label_day->Text=Convert::ToString(DayWeek[Day]);

Нужно вывести значение словаря, но у convert нет перегрузки, пытался через цикл в массив символов - не выходит, c_str - выводит True, а не значение словаря, буду очень признателен за помощь.

Text какой тип имеет, String? Попробуйте просто создать новый объект CLI-строки, передав туда указатель на данные std::string: label_day->Text = gcnew String(DayWeek[Day].c_str()).

@isnullxbh, скорее всего String^. Просто String - вообще так себе тип... Кстати, gcnew как раз с крышкой и возвращает.

Зевая... Я уже устал повторять: хотите использовать WinForms - возьмите C#. Хотите писать на C++ - возьмите GUI-фреймворк именно для C++.

Вместо приплюснутой мапы возьмите дотнетный Dictionary и не мучайтесь с конвертацией строк.

ЗЫ: L"Суббота"

Вполне подойдёт так:
label_day->Text = gcnew String(DayWeek[Day].c_ctr());

Но есть подозрение, что в общем случае правильнее
std::string &day = DayWeek[Day];
label_day->Text = gcnew String(day.c_ctr(), 0, day.length());

Хотя вообще-то логичнее было бы использовать
std::map<int, const char *> DayWeek;

label_day->Text = gcnew String(DayWeek[Day]);


Использовал третий вариант, спасибо!!

@user23328595, вероятно, как посоветовали в комментарии, лучше использовать L-строки и wchar_t.
